# Setting checkbox true or false value from helper in Meteor

Tags: html, meteor, spacebars

How can I apply the stored true or false value to the checked attribute?

I have a series of question where a user can toggle on/off (true/false) as an answer.  I have created an object called `questions` in Meteor.user().profile. The field names are the questions, and the values stored are either `true` or `false`.

[image]

Now I would like the attribute for each field to display the value stored instead of resetting to its default value.

```
<template name="template">
 {{#with currentUser.profile.questions}}
 <div class="row">
 <input  data-name="profile.questions.school" type="checkbox"  name="questions" checked="{{school}}"> Go to School?
 </div>
 <div class="row">
 <input data-name="profile.questions.contributor" type="checkbox" name="questions" checked={{contributor}}"> contributor?
 </div>
 {{/with}}
</template>
```

Am I doing this the long winded way? Would using the spacebars `{{isChecked}}` method aid in anyway? https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/spacebars-secrets-exploring-meteor-new-templating-engine/
It seems as it is simply for displaying the check box.

Comment: There's no such thing as `isChecked` in spacebars. However, using `<input type="checkbox" checked="{{value}}">`, where `value` is `true` or `false`, should work. See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#conditional-attributes-with-no-value-eg-checked-selected

Answer (score 2):

The way I handle checkboxes/radios is like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  isMyCheckboxChecked: function(value) {
    return (value == true ? 'checked' : '');
  }
});
```

Then in my template I can do:

```
<input name="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="true" {{isMyCheckboxChecked myCheckboxValue}} />
```

This assumes you are passing in a value to determine if the checkbox needs to be checked.  If your values are pretty much true/false across the board, I would even consider making the helper "global" using [Template.registerHelper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper).  The code would pretty much be the same, you would just define the helper slightly different.  This would make it available in all templates.

Comment: I tried this, am just getting `Uncaught Error: Expected valid attribute name, '', null, or object`

Comment: Try returning "checked='checked'" then

Comment: I went the other route and used `checked={{ isChecked myVar }}`. Either way the code in your solution doesn't work as-is.

Comment: Along with `return (value == 'on' ? 'checked' : false);` btw, but empty may work as well.